# The Security to the Party [Part 24]

Tags: pattern, password

A never ending party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing — his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "1 and 1", and the guest replies "1".

The second guest arrives. The security says "2 and 2", the guest replies "2".

The third guest arrives. The security says "3 and 3", the guest replies "3".

Your friend thinks he's got it all figured out, he thought that it was a crappy logical problem and at last he would have a glimpse of the hidden recipe so he walks up to the door and the security says "4 and 4". He was very confident and whispered that at last he will not be terminated which happened in the previous episodes, the security heard him and changed the question to "4 and 7". Your friend was devastated and he knew what would happen so he grabbed a pill that he hid in his pocket and he ate it and died.

Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "1 and 7" and he says "7" to get in.

Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "8 and 3" and he says "8" to get in.

You now walk up to security and get "4 and 7", what is the correct response?

hint(worthless hint but still accurate):

> Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "4 and 4" and he says "4" to get in.

hint2

> Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "0 and 1" and he says "0" to get in.

hint3

> This is another problem that doesn't include computations in it

hint4

> You need to merge the numbers but not in the mathematical way or not in a number words, just the number itself

final and a giveaway hint

> analog

i think this one is an easy one since that it was already used in the previous versions

Comment: Oh. "The Security to the Party [Part 3.5e+1442553]"

Comment: yeah, guess that i am not really good in math... that's why my puzzles do not include maths :D

Comment: I mean, how many posts in this series are going to come? :)

Comment: until we get bored with it perhaps

Comment: Probably until we create a securitytoparty.stackexchange.com :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> 9

Explanation

> Overwrite number on each other in 7 segment display
>  Write 8 over 3 to get 8
>  Write 1 over 0 to get 0

Comment: thumbs up :DDDD

Comment: Nice puzzle @KelvinBarsana!

Comment: Actually this is not the standard way a 9 is usually written on a 7-segment display.

Comment: @MohitJain:   I accept that this is the right answer; I'm just saying the puzzlecrafter was technically incorrect.   5+(7,1 or 4)=9 or 2+5=8 might have been better questions.

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 3):

My (trollish) answer:

> First, I save the game and answer 4. If I get in, I am done. If I die, I should load my saved game data back and try 7 instead.

Comment: damn you got me there, you're correct...just kidding, oh well thumbs up for trolling :D

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> `7`. Answer is the one which is bigger one b/w guard said.

Comment: oh my, didn't see that..sorry but its wrong, ill add another hint

Comment: btw thumbs up for pointing that hole :D

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this?

> 4, if the first number is an even number, you take the first number, if it's odd you take the second (0 is an even number).

Comment: uhm, possible but not the answer i was looking for..because of that, ill add another hint. and thumbs up for noticing :D

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 1):

> 7, count the characters of the first number (for example: two = 3 characters)
> So you get 1 - 3 = -2 
> one 1 = -2
> two 2 = -1
> three 3 = -1
> one 7 = 4
> eight 3 = -2
> four 7 = 2
> if the result is positive then the right number is correct

Comment: Could someone fix my spoilers D:

Comment: add this '>!' instead of this '>'

Comment: i can't seem to understand your answer, did you include a computation for that?

Comment: @KelvinBarsana I edited a bit, hope you understand it.

Comment: thumbs up for trying though

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.